# How to get the exit message of a step in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

As you can see in the [Spring Batch reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html), the table `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` has the column `EXIT_MESSAGE`. But in the corresponding Java class [`StepExecution`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecution.html) I can not find a getter for this field.

I see in my database that stacktraces are stored in this column and I would like to display them. How can I get these stacktraces?

Comment: stepExecution.getExitStatus(), I guess you  are looking for this  method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from `org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcStepExecutionDao`

> truncateExitDescription(stepExecution.getExitStatus().getExitDescription())

Answer (score 1):

Your class that implements Tasklet could also implement a [StepExecutionListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecutionListener.html). This has an afterStep method you can implement that makes the StepExecution available. From there you can use `stepExecution.getExitStatus().getExitDescription()` to get the description.